# Python Tkinter; can't assign object ID to variable in list

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to make a list of each object I add to the canvas in python. I checked online and to set the ID to a variable, the impression was you do this `idName = canvas.create_oval(x,y,x2,y2,{color},{ect...})` I tried to iterate through this, creating multiple objects, and assigning their value to a list, but it did not seem to work. I am relatively new to Tkinter and Python. Attached test code below that only returned the initial values of the list, opposed to the expected returning object ID.

```
from tkinter import *
value = [1,2,3,4,5]

window=Tk()
boardcanvas = Canvas(window, width=1000,height=500)
boardcanvas.grid(row=0,column=0,columnspan=2)

for i in range(5):
    value[i] = boardcanvas.create_rectangle(i*50,i*50,10,10,fill="red")

print(value)    
window.mainloop()
```

(The code is not supposed to make any particular image, it was taken from another program I had this issue with and modified to test getting the object ID)
(Source in case I misunderstood: https://anzeljg.github.io/rin2/book2/2405/docs/tkinter/create_oval.html)

Comment: it is indeed saving the `item_id` of all `canvas objects`. It just so happens that they are also `1, 2, 3, 4, 5`. set `value = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]` to note the difference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are saving the ID, but they are also numbered the same as your object. Tkinter saves id’s in numerical order. See comment on post.